# Simple Thread Pool Manager

Tags: c#, threadpool

I wanted a thread pool where I could set the priority of the threads and I wanted it to be very very simple. Below is the code I wrote.  It uses a bank of threads stored in four lists. If no available thread the code shifts to a different thread bank and calls the replenish method to add new threads to the bank with no available threads. The problem I'm having is despite that it can execute the delegates passed it is extremely slow. Any ideas as to why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace xThreadPool
{
    public class Pool
    {
        protected List<Tuple<AccessObject, Thread>>[] threadsOne;
        protected List<Tuple<AccessObject, Thread>> OffLoadThreads;

        private int poolSize;
        protected object threadLock = new object();
        protected object offLoadLock = new object();

        public Pool(int size)
        {            
            threadsOne = new List<Tuple<AccessObject, Thread>>[4];
            OffLoadThreads = new List<Tuple<AccessObject, Thread>>();
             poolSize = size;
            for(byte x = 0;x<4;x++)
                ReplenishThreads(x);
           
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method removes any stopped threads that were off loaded when they were running to preserve them.
        /// </summary>
        protected void RemoveDeadThreads()
        {
            lock (offLoadLock)
            {
                foreach (Tuple<AccessObject, Thread> aThread in OffLoadThreads.ToArray())
                {
                    if (aThread.Item2.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
                    {
                        OffLoadThreads.Remove(aThread);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method offloads any running threads and creates a new list to add new threads to a thread bank 
        /// from the array list indexed by z.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="z"></param>
        protected void ReplenishThreads(byte z)
        {
           
            lock (threadLock)
            {
                if(threadsOne[z] != null)
                {
                    var runningThreads = threadsOne[z].Where(x => x.Item2.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running);
                    lock (offLoadLock)
                        OffLoadThreads.AddRange(runningThreads.ToArray());
                }
                threadsOne[z] = new List<Tuple<AccessObject, Thread>>();
                for (int x = 0; x < poolSize; x++)
                {
                    var access = new AccessObject(x);
                    
                    ThreadStart aStart = new ThreadStart(access.ExecuteMethod);

                    var newEntry = new Tuple<AccessObject, Thread>(access, new Thread(aStart));
                    newEntry.Item2.Start();
                    threadsOne[z].Add(newEntry);
                }

                Task.Run(() => RemoveDeadThreads());
            }
        }        

        /// <summary>
        /// This method pushes the delegate onto a thread from a list of available threads.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="method"></param>
        /// <param name="setPriority"></param>
        public void Run(Action method, ThreadPriority setPriority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal)
        {
            Tuple<AccessObject, Thread> aThread = default;
            byte z = 0;
            do
            {
                lock (threadLock)
                {
                    aThread = threadsOne[z].Where(x =>x.Item2.ThreadState == ThreadState.Suspended).FirstOrDefault();
                    if(aThread == null)
                    {
                        Task.Run(()=>ReplenishThreads(z));
                        if (z < 3)
                            z++;
                        else
                            z = 0;
                    }
                }
            } while (aThread == null);
            aThread.Item1.MethodToStart = method;
            aThread.Item2.Priority = setPriority;
            aThread.Item2.Resume(); 
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This class is used to control a thread and exection of an applied delegate
    /// </summary>
    public class AccessObject
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public Action MethodToStart { set; get; }       

        public AccessObject(int identifier)
        {
            ID = identifier;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the executing method for the applied delegate MethodToStart
        /// </summary>
        public void ExecuteMethod()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend();
            MethodToStart();          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some custom thread pools (as code) out on the net. I used one about 5 years ago (I needed fast and slow response without pool starvation). The one I grabbed seemed well tested and supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to preserve the threads and not have to replenish them, below is the code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the executing method for the applied delegate MethodToStart
    /// </summary>
    public void ExecuteMethod()
    {
        do
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend();
            MethodToStart();
        } while (!StopThread);
    }
}
```

Here's the entire change made to the classes:

```
 public class Pool
{
    protected List<AccessObject>[] threadsOne;       

    private int poolSize;
    protected object threadLock = new object();       

    public Pool(int size)
    {            
        threadsOne = new List<AccessObject>[4];            
         poolSize = size;
        for(byte x = 0;x<4;x++)
            BuildPooledThreads(x);
       
    }
    

    /// <summary>
    /// This method creates a new list to add new threads to a thread bank 
    /// from the array list indexed by z.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="z"></param>
    protected void BuildPooledThreads(byte z)
    {
                     
        threadsOne[z] = new List<AccessObject>();
        for (int x = 0; x < poolSize; x++)
        {
            var access = new AccessObject(x);                   
                
            threadsOne[z].Add(access);
        }       
    }        

    /// <summary>
    /// This method pushes the delegate onto a thread from a list of available threads.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="method"></param>
    /// <param name="setPriority"></param>
    public void Run(Action method, ThreadPriority setPriority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal)
    {
        AccessObject aThread = default;
        byte z = 0;
        lock (threadLock)
        {
            do
            {

                aThread = threadsOne[z].Where(x => x.StoredThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Suspended).FirstOrDefault();
                if (aThread == null)
                {
                    if (z < 3)
                        z++;
                    else
                        z = 0;
                }

            } while (aThread == null);
            aThread.MethodToStart = method;
            aThread.StoredThread.Priority = setPriority;
            aThread.StoredThread.Resume();
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This class is used to control a thread and exection of an applied delegate
/// </summary>
public class AccessObject
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public Action MethodToStart { set; get; }       
    public bool StopThread { set; get; }
    public Thread StoredThread { private set; get; }

    public AccessObject(int identifier)
    {
        ID = identifier;
        StopThread = false;
        ThreadStart aStart = new ThreadStart(ExecuteMethod);
        StoredThread = new Thread(aStart);
        StoredThread.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the executing method for the applied delegate MethodToStart
    /// </summary>
    public void ExecuteMethod()
    {
        do
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend();
            MethodToStart();
        } while (!StopThread);
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach also doesn't share any of the scheduling issues that you would encounter with the ThreadPool. It really humms now and you can see (I have a 20 core system) how the pool gets the CPU usage going. That and you can set the number of threads to a small set or large set.

Comment: I cant see how a solution like this would have any advantage on a system with that many cores, you are rarely going to have a priority concern and yet introduces a whole bunch of other problems.

Comment: No there are priority issues and the difference in performance when using this approach vs the .NET Threadpool is my threaded processes get distributed across more cores and finish faster.  I haven't run into a problem so far and can't think of one that would arise.

Answer (score 0):

Starting your own threads is expensive.  Instead of doing that consider using the ThreadPool - you can still add your priority queues before sending jobs to the ThreadPool but you won't incur the cost of spinning up new threads.

Comment: Understood, but I wanted to set the priority in a way that is at the thread pool level and not the delegate level. Where I'm assuming you're thinking this line of code in the delegate: Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest; In any case the whole point of the banks was to allow for a buffer of threads to give enough time to create new threads in the pool bank.

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.Priority` sets the OS thread priority and has nothing to do with the `ThreadPool` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=net-5.0

Comment: No but is does set the priority of the running thread of the delegate that a thread calls which in effect is the pooled thread.